# If the income increases by $\$d$, will it mean the utility at the optimal point increases by $\lambda d$?

Tags: microeconomics, demand, choice-theory

I read that if the income increases by $\\\$d$, then the utility at the optimal point will increase by $\lambda d$. How do I get a sense of this, both mathematically and intuitively?

Can we write that as $\lambda = \frac{\Delta U}{\Delta I}$ where $U$ is the utility function and $I$ is the income? The preferences are assumed to be well-behaved and $p_xx + p_yy = I$ (respectively $I' = I+d$) is the budget constraint.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I guess you are asking about Envelope Theorem, you should look that up. KhanAcademy has a series on constrained optimisation, which covers that.

Comment: @Giskard See [this](https://i.imgur.com/mKqMAtz.png). In the example given, $\Delta U = 0.02 = 0.25 \cdot 0.08 = \lambda \Delta I$. Does this hold in general?

Comment: In response to the edit currently being approved: the equality will only hold for constant-returns-to-scale functions (e.g., CRS Cobb-Douglas). Try it with $U(x,y) = \ln x + \ln y$.

Answer (score 1):

> If the income increases by $d, will it mean the utility at the optimal point increases by λd?

Yes it will. For a problem:

$$\max U(x,y) \text{ s.t. } p_xx+ p_yy=I$$

we can set up a Lagrangian given by:

$$\mathcal{L} = U(x,y) - \lambda( p_xx+ p_yy - I)$$

Solving the Lagrangian above we will get some optimal demands $x^*(I)$ and $y^*(I)$. This will give us a value function:

$$U^*(x^*(I),y^*(I))=U^*(I)$$

Assuming the value function is differentiable the differential of value function is given by:

$$dU^*(I) = dU^*(x^*,y^*)= U_x'(x^*,y^*)dx^* +U_y'(x^*,y^*)dy^* \tag{*}  $$

No given the budget constraint which generally can be written as $g(x,y)=I$ where $g(x,y)=p_xx+ p_yy$, the FOCs of the Lagrangian will be given by:

$$U_x'(x^*,y^*)dx^* = \lambda g_x'(x^*,y^*)dx^* \text{ and } U_y'(x^*,y^*)dy^* = \lambda g_y'(x^*,y^*)dy^*$$

Hence * can be written as:

$$dU^*(I) =\lambda g_x'(x^*,y^*)dx^*  +\lambda g_y'(x^*,y^*)dy^*  = \lambda \left( g_x'(x^*,y^*)dx^*  + g_y'(x^*,y^*)dy^*\right) \tag{**}$$

Now if we take the differential of the budget constraint we get:

$$dg(x^*,y^*)= g_x'(x^*,y^*)dx^*  + g_y'(x^*,y^*)dy^*= dI$$

Substitute this into ** and you will get:

$$dU^*(I) = \lambda dI \text{ or } \frac{dU^*(I)}{dI} = \lambda $$

The last expression states that change in value function $U^*$ will be equal to the change in income times lambda. We could also rewrite the last expression as $U^*(I+dI)\approx \lambda dI$$.

> How do I get a sense of this, both mathematically and intuitively?

Mathematical derivation was provided above. Intuitively $\lambda$ parameter is the marginal effect of the constraints on optimal attainable value of utility.

Comment: Thank you very much. It addresses my exact question. Three quick follow-up questions if you don't mind. 1) Is this the Envelope theorem (considering you're using value function and all) that @ShaikhAmmar was referring to in the comments? 2) You showed that $dU^{*}(I) = \lambda dI$. Is it an approximation or an equality? When I tried out with a few examples, they seemed to be equal but then you have written $U^{*}(I+dI) \approx \lambda dI$ which confuses me a bit. 3) Does it work for larger changes as opposed to infinitesimal increase in income or utility?

Comment: You perhaps meant $U^{*}(I+dI) - U^{*}(I) \approx \lambda dI$. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @cris 1. it’s not direct use of envelope theorem, I used little bit roundabout way but envelope theorem gives the same result. 2. $dU^*(I)=\lambda dI$ is equality. When you replace $dU$ it becomes approximation since $dU^*(I) \approx U^*(I+dI)$. 3. It works for larger than infinitesimal changes as approximation that was point of that rewritten formula.